# Searchbar UITableView with 2 different data tables from database

Tags: objective-c, search

Right now I am creating a Searchbar. I'm using JSON to retrieve data from my database.
Currently I have these

```
    cell.textLabel.text = place.parkName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = place.parkDesc;
```

How is it possible to make the cell.textlabel.text continue with data from the other data array?

EDIT : Sorry my question was a bit confusing, what I meant was that I currently have the searchbar working but it only searches from 1 table in the database. What I'm trying to achieve is to search from 2 tables in the database.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
if(text.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else
{
    isFiltered = TRUE;
    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Places* place in placeArray)
    {
        NSRange nameRange = [place.parkName rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange descriptionRange = [place.parkDesc rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredTableData addObject:place];
        }
    }
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table View Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{  
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//return isFiltered ? searchedData.count : json.count;
//return json.count;

int rowCount;
if(self.isFiltered)
    rowCount = filteredTableData.count;
else
    rowCount = placeArray.count;

return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];

//retrieve the current city object for use with this indexpath.row


cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

Places* place;
if(isFiltered)
    place = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
    place = [placeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = place.parkName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = place.parkDesc;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to say that, once I have set cell.textLabel.text = place.parkName, how do I set it to for another array for example shop.shopName

Comment: please show your search code! thanks

Comment: I have added the search code. Further explaining, what I wanted is to have my UITableView populate with data from 2 different tables (e.g park table and shop table) in the database, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are thinking of this in the wrong way. Instead of getting one and then the other, why not just get both and merge the the arrays?

[Merge Arrays Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablearray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray%3a)

So, in short, just change the "placeArray" array to a "data" array that is the two arrays merged.

If the searching is different between the two, make one for loop for int i = 0; i < [placeArray count]; i++ and then the next loop i = [placeArray count]; i < ([placeArray count] + [shopArray count] - 1); i++

If you have any questions, just ask. I'm glad to edit this.